# Why there's a bad accuracy on dataset when it's used both for validation and training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a model with ResNet50 and got an amazing accuracy of 95% on training set.
I took the same training set for validation and the accuracy seem very bad.(<0.05%)

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_set = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,rescale=1./255,shear_range=0.2,zoom_range=0.2).flow_from_directory(data,target_size=(256,256),classes=['airplane','airport','baseball_diamond',
                                                                    'basketball_court','beach','bridge',
                                                                  'chaparral','church','circular_farmland',
                                                                  'commercial_area','dense_residential','desert',
                                                                  'forest','freeway','golf_course','ground_track_field',
                                                                  'harbor','industrial_area','intersection','island',
                                                                  'lake','meadow','medium_residential','mobile_home_park',
                                                                  'mountain','overpass','parking_lot','railway','rectangular_farmland',
                                                                  'roundabout','runway'],batch_size=31)
```

---

```
from keras.applications import ResNet50 
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras import layers,Model

conv_base = ResNet50(
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet')


for layer in conv_base.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = conv_base.output
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x) 
predictions = layers.Dense(31, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(conv_base.input, predictions)
```

---

```
# here you will write the path for train data or if you create your val data then you can test using that too. 
# test_dir = ""
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255) 
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory( 
    data, 
    target_size=(256, 256), classes=['airplane','airport','baseball_diamond',
                                                                    'basketball_court','beach','bridge',
                                                                  'chaparral','church','circular_farmland',
                                                                  'commercial_area','dense_residential','desert',
                                                                  'forest','freeway','golf_course','ground_track_field',
                                                                  'harbor','industrial_area','intersection','island',
                                                                  'lake','meadow','medium_residential','mobile_home_park',
                                                                  'mountain','overpass','parking_lot','railway','rectangular_farmland',
                                                                  'roundabout','runway'],batch_size=1,shuffle=True)
```

---

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_set,steps_per_epoch=1488//31,epochs=10,verbose=True,validation_data = test_generator,
```

### validation_steps = test_generator.samples // 31)

```
Epoch 1/10
48/48 [==============================] - 27s 553ms/step - loss: 1.9631 - acc: 0.4825 - val_loss: 4.3134 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 2/10
48/48 [==============================] - 22s 456ms/step - loss: 0.6395 - acc: 0.8212 - val_loss: 4.7584 - val_acc: 0.0833
Epoch 3/10
48/48 [==============================] - 23s 482ms/step - loss: 0.4325 - acc: 0.8810 - val_loss: 5.3852 - val_acc: 0.0625
Epoch 4/10
48/48 [==============================] - 23s 476ms/step - loss: 0.2925 - acc: 0.9153 - val_loss: 6.0963 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 5/10
48/48 [==============================] - 23s 477ms/step - loss: 0.2275 - acc: 0.9341 - val_loss: 5.6571 - val_acc: 0.0625
Epoch 6/10
48/48 [==============================] - 23s 478ms/step - loss: 0.1855 - acc: 0.9489 - val_loss: 6.2440 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 7/10
48/48 [==============================] - 23s 483ms/step - loss: 0.1704 - acc: 0.9543 - val_loss: 7.4446 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 8/10
48/48 [==============================] - 23s 487ms/step - loss: 0.1828 - acc: 0.9476 - val_loss: 7.5198 - val_acc: 0.0417
```

What could be the reason?!

Comment: You shouldn't use the same data for training and validation, that defeats the idea of validation, trying to find how well your model generalises. Please post a reproducible example

Comment: @Alistair Thank you for your reply!
This is just an experiment. Just trying to understand the reason behind low accuracy when same dataset is used as validation.

Comment: The accuracy should be the same if its the same data. Its likely an issue with the code

Comment: @Alistair No, checkout the code. This problem is likely due to overfitting as i read from various blog articles over the internet. But i am hoping to find some intuitive explanation from anybody here.

Comment: @Samuel Liew♦ I request u to please reopen the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned train_set and test_datagen differently. In particular one is flipped and scaled where the other isn't. As I mentioned in my comment, if its the same data it will have the same accuracy. You can see a model is overfitting when you use validation correctly and use unseen data for validation. Using the same data will always give the same accuracy for training and validation

Answer (score 0):

not sure what is exactly wrong but it is NOT an over fitting issue. It is clear your validation data(same as training data) is not going in correctly. For one thing you set the validation batch size =1 but you set the validation steps as validation_steps = test_generator.samples // 31) . If test_generator,samples = 1488 then you have 48 steps but with a batch size of 1 you will only validate 48  samples. You want to set the batch size and steps so that batch_size X validation_steps equals the total number of samples. That way you go through the validation set exactly one time. I also recommend that for the test generator you set shuffle=False. Also why do you bother entering all the class names. If you have your class directories labeled as 'airplane','airport','baseball_diamond' etc then you don;t need to specifically define the classes flow from directory will do that for you automatically. See documentation below.

> classes: Optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. ['dogs', 'cats']). Default: None. If not provided, the list of classes will be automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label indices, will be alphanumeric). The dictionary containing the mapping from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute class_indices.

Your training data is actually different than your test data because you are using data augmentation in the generator. That's OK it may lead to a small difference between your test and validation accuracy but your validation accuracy should be pretty close once you get the validation data to go in correctly

Comment: Hey @Gerry P , Thanks for replying!
Yeah, i wantedly set the batch size equals to 1. Because i was playing around and i tried various differnt ways but not getting good accuracy.
So Here, i made some changes. Like you pointed out, i changed the batch_size in test set to 31 and this time in validation steps, it covers the whole 1488 images during validating in each epoch.
I request u to take a look at this colab notebook,
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OJN1Q_-BtftCSQuSetaXhJAe8k0EUOwL

Comment: if you have 1448 images and 31 classes that says on average you have about 47 images per class. Even with the augmentation you are doing in the image generator I doubt that 47 images is large enough to capture the full probability distribution of the classes. As a result you will get a high training accuracy but a low validation accuracy. All I can suggest at this point is to gather more images. Try to get at least 100 images per class. and if possible keep the data set balanced by having pretty close to the same number of images per class.

Comment: I doubt that the model is currently overfitting isn't it? 
And there are 48 images per each class..... 
Total 1488imgs